# i18n for select boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

I have a model named Role. And i am using the helper below in a form. Is there a way to change the value of name attribute to another language?

```
<%= f.collection_select :role_id, Role.all, :id, name, {} -%>
```

locales/de.yml

```
de:
  role:
   admin: "something"
   editor: "something something"
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In the model:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  def translated_name
    I18n.t(name, :scope => 'role')
  end
end
```

In the view:

```
<%= f.collection_select :role_id, Role.all, :id, :translated_name -%>
```