# Activeddmin i18n. Translate form fields values

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I'm ussing *activeadmin* (1.0.0.pre2).

In my model, I have fields, filled with tags. I translate this tags in the app using the method "translate_name" in form field values (like this .. [i18n for select boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683366/i18n-for-select-boxes))

In *activeadmin* I'm using custom form to choose only some fields.

This is my activeadmin code...

```
index do
  column :user
  column :user_surname
  column :service
  column :patient_type
  column :description
  actions
end

form do |f|
  if f.object.errors.size >= 1
    f.inputs "Errors" do
      f.object.errors.full_messages.join('|')
    end
  end
  f.semantic_errors # shows errors on :base
  f.inputs :user
  f.inputs :service
  f.inputs :patient_type
  f.inputs :postal_code
  f.inputs :availability
  f.inputs :date
  f.inputs :estimated_period
  f.inputs :description
  f.actions  # adds the 'Submit' and 'Cancel' buttons
end
```

**service** y **patient_type** are nested resources exactly like this [ActiveAdmin customizing the form for belongs_to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996898/activeadmin-customizing-the-form-for-belongs-to)

*activeadmin* don't traslate this tags.

[image]

[image]

Any idea to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Formtastic you can define a `to_label` method on your models which will be
used when rendering the select field options. Also, ActiveAdmin will call a
variety of methods when searching for a name for your object, like
`display_name`. See [Index as a Table](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/a252cebb4e6b4939775df2ef6920f16bec38f884/docs/3-index-pages/index-as-table.md) docs.

Adding `to_label` and `display_name` methods to your Service class should
properly translate the values highlighted above:

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  def translated_name
    I18n.t(name)
  end

  # method used when creating Formtastic select options
  def to_label
    translated_name
  end

  # method used for displaying model names in ActiveAdmin
  def display_name
    translated_name
  end
end
```

ActiveAdmin checks objects for the following methods to show a name. Most often
the `name` method is used.

- `display_name`
- `full_name`
- `name`
- `username`
- `login`
- `title`
- `email`
- `to_s`